# Why do we not need to state new for creation of the Err object in the main method?

Tags: java, class, object, new-operator

Here is are my two classes Err, and ErrorDemo

```
class Err {
    String msg;
    int severity;
    public Err(String message,int severe) {
        msg=message;
        severity=severe;
    }
}   

public class ErrorDemo {
    String msgs[]={
        "OutPut Error",
        "Input Error",
        "Disk Full",
        "Index Out of Bounds"
    };
    int howBad[]={3,3,2,4};
    //return the error message 
    public Err getErrorMsg(int index) {
        if(index>=0&index<msgs.length) {
            return new Err(msgs[index],howBad[index]);
        } else {
            return new Err("Invalid Error Code",0);
        }
    }
}
```

In my driver class I have

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        ErrorDemo err=new ErrorDemo();
        Err e;
        e=err.getErrorMsg(2);
        System.out.println(e.msg+" Severity "+e.severity);
        e=err.getErrorMsg(19);
        System.out.println(e.msg+" Severity "+e.severity);
    }
}
```

My question  is in the Driver class we created a new ErrorDemo object, however, the Err e; object was not created as a new object in the driver but rather in the ErrorDemo class. I do not understand what is happening here can someone please explain this ??

Comment: `Err e` , e is a reference not an object

Comment: `err.getErrorMsg(2)` creates an new instance of `Err` and returns it to the `ErrorDemo` the `ErrorDemo` object.

Comment: If you want a coffee, you can do it yourself, or ask someone to do it for you. Same here. The driver can create a new Err, or it can ask another object, ErrDemo, to create it.

Comment: How would this program look if the Driver did create the new Object ?

Comment: @eli Your method getErrorMsg() has created the object for you and returned it to the reference e in the main() method. This is the reason for not using new in main().

Answer (score 1):

Ya the problem was just that I was a little thrown off by the style, I reformatted it to make it a little more readable :).

```
public class ErrorDemo {
    String msgs[]= {
        "OutPut Error",
        "Input Error",
        "Disk Full",
        "Index Out of Bounds"
    };
    int howBad[]={3,3,2,4};
    public Err getErrorMsg(int index) {
        Err test=new Err(msgs[index],howBad[index]);
        Err invalid=new Err("Invalid Error Code",0);
        if(index>=0&index<msgs.length) {
            return test;
        } else {
            return invalid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this an answer? if it is, consider pointing out what was the issue and formatting the question as per SO guidelines.